# Find the largest number smaller than a given number(n) in the given BST

Tags: binary-search-tree

Find the largest number smaller than a given number(n) in the given BST.

I tried this:

start at root node, check if root equal to n-1. If root is less than n-1  recursively call the method on root.right. If root is more than n-1 recursively call the method on root.left.

This solution works if i have a global variable to keep track to current largest element smaller that n but this is not good solution. Please let me know how to solve without global variable

Comment: Come'on from what you described, you are searching for `n-1` in BST... that won't work.

Comment: You may want to check this one out: [Possible duplication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334514/to-find-largest-element-smaller-than-k-in-a-bst)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the largest number as a parameter in your method.  When you first call it, pass in the lowest number it could possibly be.